# Storing and Retrieving data with User Forms in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently designing a check list for my office using Excel that requires the user to save anywhere from 4-10 documents that need to be saved in the same folder as this check list. I thought it might be easier to consolidate everything into one Excel file by using User Forms. I noticed that it's not safe to use a User Form to store data, but instead using it as a means to display or manipulate data or cells from within the spreadsheet.

Unfortunately, I cannot store all the raw data from these files into a single cell as they can be quite large files. I thought maybe it'd be best to have an `ActiveX Textbox` to store this data into instead, but I'm wondering if I this might cause issues later down the road or if some one else's computer isn't compatible.

**Visually what I've done...**

This is the secondary spreadsheet (will be hidden) that stores the data in ActiveX Text Boxes

[image]

User form below that is displaying that data, stored from the secondary spreadsheet in the ActiveX Text Boxes

[image]

**TL;DR**

Everything is working as intended, but my primary question here is... Is this the best and safest (safest as in, lowest chance of losing data... I am not worried about security as everything is stored on a server) way to have all this data being stored in a single document by using embedded TextBoxes? If not, what would be a good alternative?

Code run when the User Form is closed

```
Private Sub btnSaveAndClose_Click()

    Sheets("Data").TextBox1.Value = PO850Data.Value
    Sheets("Data").TextBox2.Value = Invoice810Data.Value
    frmEDIData.Hide

End Sub
```

Code run when the User Form is opened

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    btnSaveAndClose.SetFocus
    PO850Data.Value = Sheets("Data").TextBox1.Value
    Invoice810Data.Value = Sheets("Data").TextBox2.Value

End Sub
```

**EDIT 1:**

**EXAMPLE EDI 850 DOCUMENT** - *(X12 Format)*

```
ISA*01*0000000000*01*0000000000*ZZ*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO*ZZ*123456789012345*101127*1719*U*00400*000003438*0*P*>
GS*PO*4405197800*999999999*20101127*1719*1421*X*004010VICS
ST*850*000000010
BEG*00*SA*08292233294**20101127*610385385
REF*DP*038
REF*PS*R
ITD*14*3*2**45**46
DTM*002*20101214
PKG*F*68***PALLETIZE SHIPMENT
PKG*F*66***REGULAR
TD5*A*92*P3**SEE XYZ RETAIL ROUTING GUIDE
N1*ST*XYZ RETAIL*9*0003947268292
N3*31875 SOLON RD
N4*SOLON*OH*44139
PO1*1*120*EA*9.25*TE*CB*065322-117*PR*RO*VN*AB3542
PID*F****SMALL WIDGET
PO4*4*4*EA*PLT94**3*LR*15*CT
PO1*2*220*EA*13.79*TE*CB*066850-116*PR*RO*VN*RD5322
PID*F****MEDIUM WIDGET
PO4*2*2*EA
PO1*3*126*EA*10.99*TE*CB*060733-110*PR*RO*VN*XY5266
PID*F****LARGE WIDGET
PO4*6*1*EA*PLT94**3*LR*12*CT
PO1*4*76*EA*4.35*TE*CB*065308-116*PR*RO*VN*VX2332
PID*F****NANO WIDGET
PO4*4*4*EA*PLT94**6*LR*19*CT
PO1*5*72*EA*7.5*TE*CB*065374-118*PR*RO*VN*RV0524
PID*F****BLUE WIDGET
PO4*4*4*EA
PO1*6*696*EA*9.55*TE*CB*067504-118*PR*RO*VN*DX1875
PID*F****ORANGE WIDGET
PO4*6*6*EA*PLT94**3*LR*10*CT
CTT*6
AMT*1*13045.94
SE*33*000000010
GE*1*1421
IEA*1*000003438
```

These can be much larger documents, I'd say we deal with 10x this size on a regular basis. Each TextBox will store one of these document's data.

Comment: Your data is probably safe but this doesn't have a very checklist look or feel.   It's really hard to give advice without a good description of the data and what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to store a document in each textbox?  What do you consider `quite large`?   Is 1kb quite large?  1MB??

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific... Raw EDI 850 Purchase Orders are text files that similarly to a `.csv` file. Where as a `*` or `~` would be similar to a `,`. That being said... I want the user to copy this data from a website that displays it, and pasted into the TextBox from the `User Form`. These files may contain anywhere from 1000 to 50,000 characters or more long and it's hard to say what the file size may be as they can be stored in a variety of file formats (`X12`, `CSV`, `XML`). More info [here](https://www.1edisource.com/resources/edi-transactions-sets/edi-850/) on EDI 850s

Comment: Are the Textboxes meant to replace the files stored in the directory?

Comment: Not *replace*, but used as a quick reference; as the original files are being stored by a separate service that we pull from

Comment: There is no compatibility issues using the `Active X  TextBox`.   There is little chance of losing data the way that you are using it.  I personally would not do things this way because it aesthetically ugly.  Writing the data a worksheet gives you so many more options to work with the data.

Comment: @ThomasInzina well these `ActiveX TextBox`es are stored in a hidden sheet, so they wont even see them anyways... I just wanted to know if it's a safe method.

Comment: There is probably a slightly greater chance of the workbook getting corrupted but not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589579/is-it-possible-to-store-elements-of-array-permanently-in-vba-in-excel

Summary:
To store data persistently in the workbook using VBA, you have a few options:

- Store it in another worksheet. If you don't want the user to be able to see the worksheet, `Sheets("ArrayValuesWorksheet").Visible = xlVeryHidden`
- Create a defined name which has the desired data as its value. `Names("MyArrayData") = myArray`
- Store it in `ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406585/vba-set-custom-document-property
- Store it in a `CommandBar`, hopefully the user won't find it
- Use a helper XLL which can call `Excel4(xlDefineBinaryName,...)` and `Excel4(xlGetBinaryName)`

I believe storing in a hidden sheet is the most common.

Comment: I've taken into consideration about storing it in a hidden sheet, however I am unable to store it in a single cell as the data can be quite large and I'd rather not take that approach. Is it still safe to do so with what I have currently?

Comment: It's definitely safe to store it in multiple cells in a hidden sheet. I am not aware of anyone recommending using ActiveX objects to store things; in previous versions of Excel this was crash-prone. Perhaps it's better now.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Very excellent resources you posted here :)